# How to pass a variable to Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using ReactJS and Redux and I'm trying to pass the "locale" variable from **Login.js** to **authActions.js**. The locale variable simply denotes the language used.

I've tried adding it as a parameter in **reduxForm**, but locale is undefined there. So then I tried defining it, by retrieving it from the LocaleContext hook, but hooks aren't allowed (I also cannot retrieve it in authActions for this reason).

What would be a good solution to get **locale** into authActions? All I want to do is translate the error messages in authActions.

**Login.js**

```
function Login(props) {
  const { handleSubmit, error } = props;
  const locale = React.useContext(LocaleContext);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          component={renderField}
          type="text"
          validate={[
            required({
              message: "this field is required",
            }),
          ]}
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field
          name="password"
          label={getTranslation(locale, Translations.Password)}
          component={renderField}
          type="password"
          validate={[
            required({
              message: "this field is required",
            }),
          ]}
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        {renderError(error)}

        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
          <Translation translation={Translations.Log_in} />
        </Button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "login",
  onSubmit: loginUser,
  locale: locale, // This doesn't work, locale is undefined
})(Login);
```

**authActions.js**

```
export function loginUser(formValues, dispatch, props) {

  const locale = React.useContext(LocaleContext); // Doesn't work - cannot use hooks here.

  const loginUrl = AuthUrls.LOGIN;

  return axios
    .post(loginUrl, formValues)
    .then((response) => {
      const token = response.data.key;
      dispatch(authLogin(token));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      history.push("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("how do I get locale here?", locale);

      const processedError = processServerError(error.response.data);
      throw new SubmissionError(processedError);
    });
}

export function authLogin(token) {
  return {
    type: AuthTypes.LOGIN,
    payload: token,
  };
}
```

Comment: i think the easiest way, would be to add hidden `Field` with `locale` value to the form, and it will be available inside `formValues`

Comment: @Montecamo That's actually pretty smart. How do I make a hidden field though? :)

Comment: but the better solution will be to throw some error code, inside your actions, and then translate this error code inside your component

Comment: just set `display: none` to it :)

Comment: @Montecamo Alright that works, now how can I assign a value to the empty form? :) I tried value="..." but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Montecamo And regarding translating the error code inside component: I can't seem to access the field specific errors...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, and wanted to share it in case someone else is stuck with this problem. I simply used props.initialize in useEffect to add a new value to my form. Then in authActions I simply call formValues.locale.

I'll wait before choosing the correct answer, in case someone has a better solution than this.

**Login.js**

```
function Login(props) {
  const { handleSubmit, error } = props;
  const locale = React.useContext(LocaleContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.initialize({ locale: locale });
  }, [locale]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          component={renderField}
          type="text"
          validate={[
            required({
              message: "this field is required",
            }),
          ]}
        />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <Field
          name="password"
          label={getTranslation(locale, Translations.Password)}
          component={renderField}
          type="password"
          validate={[
            required({
              message: "this field is required",
            }),
          ]}
        />
      </fieldset>

    <fieldset className="form-group" style={{ display: "none" }}>
      <Field
        name="locale"
        label="locale"
        component={renderField}
        type="text"
        validate={[
          required({
            message: getTranslation(locale, Translations.FieldRequired),
          }),
        ]}
      />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset className="form-group" style={{ display: "none" }}>
      <Field name="locale" component={renderField} />
    </fieldset>

      <fieldset className="form-group">
        {renderError(error)}

        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
          <Translation translation={Translations.Log_in} />
        </Button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "login",
  onSubmit: loginUser,
  locale: locale, // This doesn't work, locale is undefined
})(Login);
```

**authActions.js**

```
export function loginUser(formValues, dispatch, props) {

  const locale = formValues.locale; // WORKS!

  const loginUrl = AuthUrls.LOGIN;

  return axios
    .post(loginUrl, formValues)
    .then((response) => {
      const token = response.data.key;
      dispatch(authLogin(token));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      history.push("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Locale is here!", locale);

      const processedError = processServerError(error.response.data);
      throw new SubmissionError(processedError);
    });
}

export function authLogin(token) {
  return {
    type: AuthTypes.LOGIN,
    payload: token,
  };
}
```